# How to create a new role and assign it to all users of a guild?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I try to make my first discord bot. The bot should create a new role then assign it to all users of the guild. How can I achieve it?

Here my code, although it doesn't work:

```
bot.on('guildCreate', function(guild) {
    guild.roles.create({
        data: {
            name: 'Authorized2',
            color: 'GREEN',
        },
        reason: 'we needed a role for Super Cool People',
    }).then(guild.members.forEach(member => member.roles.add(role)));
});
```

I receive the following error: `guild.members.forEach is not a function`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to access members array using `members.cache`

```js
bot.on('guildCreate', function(guild) {
    guild.roles.create({
        data: {
            name: 'Authorized2',
            color: 'GREEN',
        },
        reason: 'we needed a role for Super Cool People',
    }).then(guild.members.cache.forEach(member => member.roles.add(role)));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- `members` is a Manager, so you need to access the `.cache` property before you can use the `.forEach` method
- You try to add `role` in `member.roles.add(role)`, and while you receive the `role` in the `then()` method, you forgot to add an arrow function with it

```js
bot.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
  guild.roles
    .create({
      data: {
        name: 'Authorized2',
        color: 'GREEN',
      },
      reason: 'we needed a role for Super Cool People',
    })
    .then((role) =>
      guild.members.cache.forEach((member) => member.roles.add(role)),
    );
});
```

Comment: We progress : when the bot enters the server, the role is created but only assigned to the bot and not to the other members already present on the server